# How to get access to host wifi interface from docker container

Tags: wifi, kali-linux, docker

I have docker container of debian-based OS(I'm using `kalilinux/kali-linux-docker` image). How can I gain access to my host wifi adapter from that container?

I'm using:

- Docker CE 17.06.0-ce-win19 (12801)
- Laptop is on Windows 10
- USB wifi adapter
- Start container using this command `docker run -it --privileged --net="host" --rm kalilinux/kali-linux-docker bash`

Here is `iwconfig` output:

```
root@moby:/# iwconfig
br-bddc8b9f6f97  no wireless extensions.
eth0      no wireless extensions.
gre0      no wireless extensions.
br-b83648b3ccb6  no wireless extensions.
ip6tnl0   no wireless extensions.
br-ce31ec8a7751  no wireless extensions.
bond0     no wireless extensions.
lo        no wireless extensions.
dummy0    no wireless extensions.
teql0     no wireless extensions.
ip6_vti0  no wireless extensions.
ip_vti0   no wireless extensions.
tunl0     no wireless extensions.
docker0   no wireless extensions.
ip6gre0   no wireless extensions.
gretap0   no wireless extensions.
hvint0    no wireless extensions.
sit0      no wireless extensions.
```

So, there are neither integrated nor USB wifi adapter in the list

Comment: Maybe, this might help you : [wiki : Container-access-to-wireless-network-interface](https://github.com/fgg89/docker-ap/wiki/Container-access-to-wireless-network-interface)

Answer (score 6):

First install this three tools,
`apt-get install kali-linux kali-linux-wireless kali-linux-top10`

Now commit changes to image,
`docker commit <CONTAINER ID> <IMAGE NAME>`

Find image id of newly created docker image,
`docker images`

Time for magic,
`docker run -it --net="host" --privileged <IMAGE NAME> /bin/bash`

Source: [Run Airmon-ng from VM without external “USB Wireless card”](https://deshmukhsuraj.wordpress.com/2015/06/30/run-airmon-ng-from-vm-without-external-usb-wireless-card/)

Comment: packages were renamed to kali-tools-wireless and kali-tools-top10

Comment: how to access host built wifi adapter ?